# Git adds empty line after commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

Why git adds this line after commit even I haven't done it by myself?
It's screenshot from bitbucket PR review.
[image]

Comment: Git does nothing of the sort. Must be your editor ("remove trailing whitespace on save" or something like that)

Comment: It might also be your frontend to git. I know [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) has some settings to change line endings on commit or checkout. Never used them because it will only confuse everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you posted shows removal of several whitespaces on line 12, not addition of a new line. Git does not edit your files, this is most likely done by your IDE's autoformatting tools.